# Sum from rolling window of varying lengths

Tags: python, list, sum

I'm trying to find a particular sum from part of a list using a rolling window of various lengths.  To start, I created a basic list of numbers, then tried to sum some of the rolling windows generated.  Unfortunately, it does not appear possible to do this.

```
foo = []

for x in range (1, 200): 
    foo.append(x)

def subsequences(iterable, length):
    return [iterable[i: i + length] for i in xrange(len(iterable) - length + 1)]

for i in range (1, len(foo)):
    print sum(subsequences(foo, i))
```

The error I receive is:

*TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'*

Is there a way I can generate each subsequence and sum them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspecting the output of `subsequences()` reveals the problem: You're attempting to add a sequence of lists together, to achieve the sum of the integer values contained in each list.

```
print(subsequences(foo, i))
# [[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8] ...]
```

That's not what Python's built-in `sum` is designed for, but this operation will work if you use Numpy's `sum`:

```
import numpy as np

# ... 

for i in range (1, len(foo)):
    print (np.sum(subsequences(foo, i)))
```

Output:

```
19900
39600
59100
78400
97500
116400
...
```

Alternately, you can extract the values in each list before applying `sum`, but using Numpy lets you keep your code exactly as is, just add `np.` and you're good.

Comment: But... then you have to install numpy

Comment: @Ben pretty easy if you have `pip`.

Comment: @RoadRunner last time I tried I ran into dependency issues. But even if it's gotten completely trivial, I don't think it's worth installing the whole thing just for `numpy.sum`. Just my opinion, there are reasonable arguments for installing it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to sum the subsequences:

```
[sum(subsequence) for subsequence in subsequences(foo, i)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You're attempting to sum lists, when you want to sum numbers instead. If you run something as simple as:

```
>>> print(sum([[1], [2]]))
.....
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'
```

You will replicate your `TypeError`, which is currently the behavior of your program.

To resolve this, just break down the problem.

First have a look at each sub sequence for one iteration such as `2`:

```
print([x for x in subsequence(foo, 2)])
# [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5], [5, 6], [6, 7], [7, 8], [8, 9], [9, 10], [10, 11], ......]
```

Then sum each of the subsequences with:

```
print([sum(x) for x in subsequences(foo, 2)])
# [3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, ......]
```

Then sum this list:

```
print(sum(sum(x) for x in subsequences(foo, 2)))
# 39600
```

Your final for loop would then behave correctly for all iterations of `i`:

```
for i in range (1, len(foo)):
    print(sum(sum(x) for x in subsequences(foo, i)))
```

Which behaves correctly:

```
19900
39600
59100
78400
97500
116400
135100
153600
171900
190000
207900
225600
243100
......
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` to "push `sum` down one level of list nesting"; for example:

```
map(sum, subsequences(foo, 4))

# [10, 14, 18, 22, 26, 30, 34, 38, 42, 46, 50, 54, 58, 62, 66, 70, ...
```

A more efficient way is to compute the cumulative sum first and then take pairwise differences at a suitable offset. You appear to be on python 2 which is a pity because python 3 has an accumulate function. On python 2 we need to build our own:

```
def partialsums(a):
    def runner(a):
        runner.tot += a
        return runner.tot
    runner.tot = 0
    return [0] + [runner(i) for i in a]

ps = partialsums(foo)
```

Now you can simply do:

```
[r-l for r, l in zip(ps[4:], ps[:-4])]
# [10, 14, 18, 22, 26, 30, 34, 38, 42, 46, 50, 54, 58, 62, 66, 70, ...

[r-l for r, l in zip(ps[100:], ps[:-100])]
# [5050, 5150, 5250, 5350, 5450, 5550, 5650, 5750, 5850, 5950, 6050, ...
```

This last example takes a bit below 10,000 arithmetic operations with the direct method compared to just 300 with the difference method and of these 300, 200 need only be done once and can be reused for other window lengths.